# Adwords API OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: python, google-ads-api

i am trying to add campaign for testing. I can get account hierarchy. But when i execute the add_campaign.py code i get this error :

```
campaigns = campaign_service.mutate(operations) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleads/common.py", line 1389, in MakeSoapRequest e.detail, errors=error_list, message=e.message) googleads.errors.GoogleAdsServerFault: [OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ operations[0], OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ operations[1]]
```

my developer token is from manager account

client id is from test account

client secret is from test account

refresh token is get with test account IDs

client customer id is from test account

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with PHP SDK.
Did you find any solution?